# Vanilla JavaScript carousel translate issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to build a carousel with only Vanilla JavaScript but I encounter some issues along the way. The carousel should display 5 items on the page from a total of 10, and when the "next" button is clicked should slide 3 elements. The problem is that will continue to translateX after the last element in the slider was reached.

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector("[data-target='carousel']");
const card = carousel.querySelector("[data-target='card']");
const leftButton = document.querySelector("[data-action='slideLeft']");
const rightButton = document.querySelector("[data-action='slideRight']");

const carouselWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
const cardStyle = card.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(card);
const cardMarginRight = Number(cardStyle.marginRight.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
const cardCount = carousel.querySelectorAll("[data-target='card']").length;

let offset = 0;
const maxX = -((cardCount / 3) * carouselWidth + cardMarginRight * (cardCount / 3) - carouselWidth - cardMarginRight);

// click events
leftButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (offset !== 0) {
    offset += carouselWidth + cardMarginRight;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  }
});

rightButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (offset !== maxX) {
    offset -= carouselWidth + cardMarginRight;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  }
});
```

```css
  .wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .button-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .carousel {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
  .card {
    background: black;
    min-width: 344px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 45px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="carousel" data-target="carousel">
     <li class="card" data-target="card">1</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">2</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">3</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">4</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">5</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">6</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">7</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">8</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">9</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">10</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button data-action="slideLeft">left</button>
  <button data-action="slideRight">right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line, you should not set it to equal because if that's not equal it continues sliding

```
if (offset !== maxX)
```

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector("[data-target='carousel']");
const card = carousel.querySelector("[data-target='card']");
const leftButton = document.querySelector("[data-action='slideLeft']");
const rightButton = document.querySelector("[data-action='slideRight']");

const carouselWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
const cardStyle = card.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(card);
const cardMarginRight = Number(cardStyle.marginRight.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
const cardCount = carousel.querySelectorAll("[data-target='card']").length;

let offset = 0;
const maxX = -((cardCount / 3) * carouselWidth + cardMarginRight * (cardCount / 3) - carouselWidth - cardMarginRight);

// click events
leftButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (offset !== 0) {
    offset += carouselWidth + cardMarginRight;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  }
});

rightButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (offset+500 > maxX) {
    offset -= carouselWidth + cardMarginRight;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  }
});
```

```css
  .wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .button-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .carousel {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
  .card {
    background: black;
    min-width: 344px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 45px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="carousel" data-target="carousel">
     <li class="card" data-target="card">1</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">2</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">3</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">4</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">5</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">6</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">7</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">8</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">9</li>
    <li class="card" data-target="card">10</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button data-action="slideLeft">left</button>
  <button data-action="slideRight">right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the more or less fixed width of each card which leads to different results on different screen sizes.

```
min-width: 344px;
```

Ive changed to (just for example)

```
min-width: 19%; <!-- you need 5 cards on screen -->
```

and in your JavaScript something like this:

```
// get card size
const cardWidth = card.offsetWidth;

//and later on e.g for button to the right do offset 3 cards
offset -= (cardWidth + cardMarginRight) * 3;
```